Perform spatial joins
I am trying to join a portion of a county data with structures (buildings) data
Structures data looks like:

County data looks like this:

Using Databricks to run this join.
Approach taken so far:
Created hex id's for both the structures and county data with different resolutions, but unable to get all the structures within the county. Most structures in the boundary struggles.
Another approach is to use mosaic library and create mosaic index for both the data and then join on index and is_core (https://databrickslabs.github.io/mosaic/api/spatial-indexing.html)
Another approach is to take points from structures and do st_intersect - which doesn't provide enough result as well and also took more than 2 days to compute.
What would be the best approach to do a join within these two data?
Here is a sample code I tried that uses mosaic index to join
structs_withIndex = (
  structs
    .withColumn(
      "st_mosaic_index", 
      mos.grid_tessellateexplode(col("wkt"), lit(9))
    )
)

county_withIndex = (
      county
        .withColumn(
          "c_mosaic_index", 
          mos.grid_tessellateexplode(col("wkt"), lit(9))
        )
    )

joined_ = (
  county_withIndex.join(
    structs_withIndex,
    fema_withIndex["c_mosaic_index.index_id"] == structs_withIndex["st_mosaic_index.index_id"]
  ).where(
    # If the county is a core chip (the chip is fully contained within the geometry), then we do not need
    # to perform any intersection, because any point matching the same index will certainly be contained in
    # the county. Otherwise we need to perform an st_contains operation on the chip geometry.
    col("fp_mosaic_index.is_core") | mos.st_contains(col("c_mosaic_index.wkb"), col("st_mosaic_index.wkb"))
  )
)


It's pyspark in Databricks. Not using any GIS softwares
